# Jabref: Images in exported HTML bibliography

Tags: html, image, export, bibtex, bibliography

I use Jabref to export an html file with a table of publications. 
I would also like to embed images of the front covers into my exported table but I don't get it working.

In my export filter I state:

```
<td><img src="{\file}" width="100"></td>
```

But in the source code the result looks like this:

```
<td><img src="{:imagename.jpg:JPG image}" width="100"></td>
```

So my problem is that I need to reference to the file name without the brackets etc. Is there a way to do this I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I received this answer from the JabRef User mailing List and it seems to work out:

> have a look at: http://jabref.sourceforge.net/help/CustomExports.php
>
> according to the side you should try the following:

```
<td><img src="\format[WrapFileLinks(\p)]{\file}" width="100"></td>
```